# Error with useSearchParams() and Prerendering Pages in Next.js Docker Build

Tags: docker, next.js, deployment, build, vercel

Link to the code that reproduces this issue
https://github.com/morganwestcoding/forme-nextjs

To Reproduce
I'm encountering an error when attempting to build my Next.js application with Docker. The build process fails during the prerendering of pages, citing issues with useSearchParams() not being wrapped in a suspense boundary and prerender errors on several pages.

Steps to Reproduce:

Clone the repo: https://github.com/morganwestcoding/forme-nextjs
Run npm install
Start the development server with npm run dev to ensure it works
Execute docker build . in the terminal

Current vs. Expected behavior
Expected Result: The Docker build completes without errors.

Actual Result: The build fails with errors related to useSearchParams() and pre-rendering pages.

If you can also help me deploy to vercel i can provide rewards been trying to solve this for 2 weeks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does `npm run build` complete without error?